# Как в библиотеке Glide убрать кеширование картинок при загрузке из интернета?

Tags: java

```
Glide.with(context)
    .load("http://inthecheesefactory.com/uploads/source/glidepicasso/cover.jpg")
    .into(ivImg);
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вызывать [`diskCacheStrategy()`](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/javadocs/latest/com/bumptech/glide/DrawableRequestBuilder.html#diskCacheStrategy%28com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DiskCacheStrategy%29) с [`DiskCacheStrategy.NONE`](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/javadocs/latest/com/bumptech/glide/load/engine/DiskCacheStrategy.html#NONE), как сказано [тут](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/wiki/Caching-and-Cache-Invalidation):

```
diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
```